# Converting Python into portable bytecode

Tags: python, c, gcc, cython, header-files

I've written **a short Python script**, which I would like to be **portable**, in the sense that it could run on a variety of very **stripped-down systems**, on which it may not be possible to install Python.

At first, I turned to **Cython**. My plan was:

1. Use Cython to compile my Python script into C.
2. Use GCC to compile the C into bytecode.
3. Run the bytecode anywhere.

Step (1) was easy. I ran `cython my_script.py`, and it dutifully spat out my_script.c. Step (2) is where I'm stuck at the moment. Running `gcc my_script.c` was more troublesome. Initially, I got compile errors of the form: `header_file.h: No such file or directory`. I could resolve these by copying and pasting the files in question from /usr/include/ into the same directory as my_script.c, but then I ran into the next problem, dozens of errors of the form: `undefined reference to Something_or_Other`. Does anyone know where I might be going wrong? I've already run `sudo apt install python3-dev`, and I've tried `gcc my_script.c -I/user/include/`, but neither seems to achieve anything.

I've also considered just writing my script in C. However, the thing that I'm trying to write involves both dictionaries and Unicode characters, both of which are a real headache in C.

Comment: I'm not convinced GCC can compile into "run anywhere" bytecode. Typically it produces files fairly tied to a specific CPU

Comment: The undefined reference errors tell you that you need to link to a library (which is different from "including" it)

Comment: @DavidW I would be grateful if you could elaborate on the distinction between the two.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096152/c-difference-between-linking-library-and-adding-include-directories looks reasonably comprehensive. Essentially the `#include "some_header.h" tells C that some functions exist; the linking step provides the implementation.